Which PHP package version is currently in use
When I install php package with sudo apt install php-mysql. It installs two packages. Which one is in use? Are these really two packages or php-mysql is an alias like a symlink current package in use?
sudpo apt list --installed outputs
php-mysql/noble,now 2:8.3+93ubuntu2 all [installed]
php8.3-mysql/noble,now 8.3.6-0maysync1 amd64 [installed,automatic


If you use apt show package_name for each, you'll see  more information.
To sum it up, php-mysql provides a mysql module and a dependency for the default PHP package which is php8.3-common.  It basically provides some of the documentation which can be seen the following command which show the files that it provides which are the copyright and changelog:
dpkg-query -L php-mysql

php8.3-mysql provides the modules for PHP which are used to interact with MySQL including php-mysqli php-mysqlnd php-pdo-mysql php8.3-mysqli php8.3-mysqlnd php8.3-pdo-mysql as well as some other things.
The following command show this in the files that it provides:
dpkg-query -L php8.3-mysql

apt show and dpkg-query -L are useful for finding such information on packages.
